# Convert pandas series to int with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series (month_addded) in my DataFrame like this:

```
9.0
12.0
12.0
nan
1.0
```

I want all the floats to be ints, and the NaN's to stay as they are. I did this:

```
for i in df['month_added']:
    if i > 0:
        i=int(i)
```

But it did nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NaN` is float typed, so Pandas would always downcast your column to float as long as you have `NaN`. You can use [Nullable Integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type), available from Pandas 0.24.0:

```
df['month_added'] = df['month_added'].astype('Int64')
```

If that's not possible, you can force `Object` type (not recommended):

```
df['month_added'] = pd.Series([int(x) if x > 0 else x for x in df.month_added], dtype='O')
```

Or since your data is positive and `NaN`, you can mask `NaN` with `0`:

```
df['month_added'] = df['month_added'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: "df['month_added'] = df['month_added'].astype('Int64')" Solved it. Thank you!